# Can not install .ipa

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

since I updated the macos, the xcode, the nativescript version, I can't install any application on ios. When I create one from 0 I can install it but not open it, after the launch screen appears crashed, and no errors appear.

Provide version numbers for the following components (information can be retrieved by running tns info in your project folder or by inspecting the package.json of the project):

- CLI: 6.0.2
- tns-core-moules: 6.0.5
- Plugin(s): camera, firebase, bandscanner
- xcode 10.3
- tns-ios: 6.01
- NativeScript-Angular: ^8.1.0
- Angular: 8.0.0
  i Tryed:
  create 1001 new certificates, regenerating appIDs, profiles ...
  remove platforms
  remove hooks
  remove node modules
  update pods
  update nativescript
  update webpack
  migrate
  build ios
  prepare ios
  when I create an app from scratch (with the same appid) I get to install it but I can't open it it doesn't happen from the launchscreen

I almost always get the error you can't install the app
other times I returned the error from xcode 65 0 70 ..
You cannot identify the type of development profile or you do not have permissions to access the Wi-Fi .. when you can.

[image: error install]

log trace:

```
Trying to get macOS version.
Exec system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType -detailLevel mini 
 stdout: Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.14.6 (18G87)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 18.7.0
      Time since boot: 3:35


 stderr: 
macOS version based on system_profiler is 10.14.
Error: Trying to handle SIGINT event. CLI overrides this behavior and does not allow handling SIGINT as this causes issues with Ctrl + C in terminal
    at process.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/nativescript-cli.js:22:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:122:15
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:120:21)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:35:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/proper-lockfile/lib/lockfile.js:296:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
Looking for project in '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp'
Project directory is '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp'.
Loading extensions.
Asserting extension nativescript-cloud is installed.
Extension nativescript-cloud is installed.
Asserting extension nativescript-starter-kits is installed.
Extension nativescript-starter-kits is installed.
System information:
[Object: null prototype] {
  platform: 'darwin',
  shell: '/bin/bash',
  os:
   'Darwin iMac-de-usuario.lan 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jun 20 18:42:21 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.270.47~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64\n',
  procArch: 'x64',
  nodeVer: '10.16.0',
  npmVer: '6.9.0',
  nodeGypVer: null,
  nativeScriptCliVersion: '6.0.2',
  gitVer: '2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)',
  dotNetVer: null,
  javacVersion: '1.8.0_222',
  javaVersion: '1.8.0_222',
  adbVer: '1.0.41',
  androidInstalled: true,
  monoVer: null,
  gradleVer: null,
  isAndroidSdkConfiguredCorrectly: true,
  xcodeVer: '10.3.0',
  xcodeprojLocation: '/usr/local/bin/xcodeproj',
  itunesInstalled: true,
  cocoaPodsVer: '1.7.5',
  isCocoaPodsWorkingCorrectly: true,
  isCocoaPodsUpdateRequired: false,
  pythonInfo: { isInstalled: true, isSixPackageInstalled: true } }
spawn: /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/detached-processes/cleanup-process.js" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/bootstrap.js"
Exec npm view tns-core-modules  versions --json 

 stderr: 
Initializing analytics statuses.
Analytics statuses:  { TrackFeatureUsage: 'enabled', TrackExceptions: 'enabled' }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Check Local Build Setup',
  label: 'Starting',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: undefined }
spawn: /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/analytics/analytics-broker-process.js" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/bootstrap.js"
Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
CocoaPods are installed.
CocoaPods update is not required.
CocoaPods are configured properly.
Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
Python installed and configured correctly.
The Python 'six' package is found.
Xcode version 10.3.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Check Local Build Setup',
  label: 'Finished: Is setup correct: true',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: undefined }
Validate options for platform: iOS
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'pageview',
  path: 'run ios',
  title: 'run ios',
  customDimensions: { cd5: 'Unknown', cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false' } }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Options',
  label:
   '{"log":"trace","$0":"_localpath","bundle":"webpack","profileDir":"private"}',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: undefined }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'PreviewAppData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Preview App Data',
  platform: 'iOS',
  label: 'iOS',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' } }
Searching for devices...
startLookingForDevices; platform is iOS
Options for ios-device-discovery { platform: 'iOS',
  shouldReturnImmediateResult: false,
  emulator: false }
Starting to look for iOS devices.
Found device with identifier 'fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293'
startLookingForDevices; platform is iOS
Options for ios-device-discovery { platform: 'iOS',
  shouldReturnImmediateResult: false,
  emulator: false }
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command prepare is before-prepare
Preparing project...
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command watch is before-watch
spawn: /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node "--max_old_space_size=4096" "/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" "--preserve-symlinks" "--config=/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/webpack.config.js" "--env.hmr" "--env.ios" "--env.appPath=src" "--env.appResourcesPath=App_Resources" "--env.verbose" "--env.sourceMap" "--watch"
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Performance',
  label: 'WebpackCompilerService__startWebpackProcess',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: 3 }
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 32914f7062562fe4d886
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 16792ms
Built at: 06/08/2019 13:02:24
                                            Asset       Size                                          Chunks             Chunk Names
                                        bundle.js    123 KiB                                          bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                     package.json  112 bytes                                                  [emitted]  
                                       runtime.js   71.4 KiB                                         runtime  [emitted]  runtime
tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js  664 bytes  tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules  [emitted]  tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules
                                        vendor.js   14.3 MiB                                          vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
Entrypoint tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules = runtime.js vendor.js tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 918 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 653 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 167 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 5.65 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 1.86 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.css] 56 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.html] 263 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.ts] 17.7 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/item/item-detail.component.html] 394 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/item/item-detail.component.ts] 977 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/item/item.service.ts] 1.59 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/item/items.component.html] 1.68 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/item/items.component.ts] 1010 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 2.09 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 467 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command watchPatterns is before-watchPatterns
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command watchPatterns is after-watchPatterns
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command prepareNativeApp is before-prepareNativeApp
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command checkForChanges is before-checkForChanges
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.AspectFill.imageset.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.Center.imageset
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/LaunchScreen.Center.imageset.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/App_Resources/iOS.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/Headers
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/Headers.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/Modules
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/Modules.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-camera/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-camera/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-geolocation/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-geolocation/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework/Headers
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework/Headers.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework/Modules
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework/Modules.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSCrashlyticsLogger.framework.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework/Headers
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework/Headers.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework/Modules
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework/Modules.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/TNSMLKitCamera.framework.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-wifi-info/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/nativescript-wifi-info/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/src.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/typings
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios/typings.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules/platforms/ios.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework/Headers
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework/Headers.
containsNewerFiles will check /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework/Modules
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework/Modules.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios/TNSWidgets.framework.
containsNewerFiles returns false for /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios.
Set nativeChanged to false.
Set value of configChanged to false
checkForChanges returns ProjectChangesInfo {
  appResourcesChanged: false,
  nativeChanged: false,
  configChanged: false,
  nativePlatformStatus: '3' }
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command checkForChanges is after-checkForChanges
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command prepareNativeApp is after-prepareNativeApp
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Performance',
  label: 'PrepareNativePlatformService__prepareNativePlatform',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: 1698 }
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command watch is after-watch
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command prepare is after-prepare
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Performance',
  label: 'PrepareController__prepareCore',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: 49889 }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'LiveSync',
  label: 'iOS_Device_12.3.1',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: undefined }
Getting applications information for devices with identifiers: fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293
Received multiple results:
{ fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293:
   [ { deviceId: 'fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293',
       response: [Array] } ] }
Result when getting applications information:  [
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "org.nativescript.play",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  },
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "org.nativescript.preview",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  },
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.google.chrome.ios",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  }
]
Installing on device fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293...
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Deploy',
  label: 'iOS_Device_12.3.1',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'Unknown' },
  value: undefined }
Getting applications information for devices with identifiers: fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293
Received multiple results:
{ fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293:
   [ { deviceId: 'fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293',
       response: [Array] } ] }
Result when getting applications information:  [
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "org.nativescript.play",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  },
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "org.nativescript.preview",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  },
  {
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.google.chrome.ios",
    "IceniumLiveSyncEnabled": false,
    "configuration": ""
  }
]
Project dir from hooksArgs is: undefined.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
BeforeHookName for command install is before-install
Installing /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on devices with identifiers: fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293.
Error while executing ios device operation: Could not install application with code: -402653109
Failed to install /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on device with identifier fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Could not install application
Unable to apply changes on device: fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Failed to install /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on device with identifier fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Could not install application.
Will emit event runOnDeviceError with data { projectDir:
   '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp',
  deviceIdentifier: 'fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293',
  applicationIdentifier: 'com.name.qapplication',
  error:
   { Error: Failed to install /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on device with identifier fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Could not install application
       at Errors.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:126:28)
       at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:136:21)
       at $iosDeviceOperations.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-application-manager.js:45:30)
       at IOSDeviceOperations.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:201:25)
       at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
       at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:11:65)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
     name: 'Exception',
     message:
      'Failed to install /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on device with identifier fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Could not install application',
     stack:
      'Error: Failed to install /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/qapp.ipa on device with identifier fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293. Error is: Could not install application\n    at Errors.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:126:28)\n    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:136:21)\n    at $iosDeviceOperations.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-application-manager.js:45:30)\n    at IOSDeviceOperations.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:201:25)\n    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)\n    at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/mobile/ios/device/ios-device-operations.js:11:65)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)',
     errorCode: 127,
     suppressCommandHelp: true,
     proxyAuthenticationRequired: false,
     printOnStdout: undefined } }
Stopping webpack watch for platform ios.
Project dir from hooksArgs is: /Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp.
Hooks directories: [ '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp/hooks' ]
AfterHookName for command watch is after-watch
Will emit event runOnDeviceStopped with data { projectDir:
   '/Users/usuario/eclipse-workspace/Qapp_movil/qapp',
  deviceIdentifier: 'fe2ac05d75a124792305ceb856a07c80ad987293' }
Webpack process exited with code null when we expected it to be long living with watch.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right provisional profile and it includes your device id? Have you enabled developer mode on device?

Comment: Hi Manoj,
yes, i used tns run ios --provision ("my profile").

My devices are ios and are registered in the profiles, try to delete them and register them again.
my project worked before perfectly on ios, but after updating the mac, nativescript and xcode...